# Flutter: The flutter reverse engineering makes using the firebase in the flutter directly not safe

Tags: flutter, firebase

Usually, our `flutter_app` is made from `flutter_project`.
Is there a program that can reverse engineering the `flutter_app` back to `flutter_project`?
Is it possible?

If it is possible.
So, then using firebase directly on flutter is not safe, right?

Example:
when you click to buy something in the app

1. Get the latest product price information
2. Get the latest user money information
3. Check enough money
4. Add this order
5. Update user's money after deduction of the product cost

If someone reverse engineering the app back to flutter_project Then delete the logic in item 5. It will not waste money like this.

Now I want to use firebase, but I'm afraid to write on flutter.
Is it possible for the program that can reverse engineering the `flutter_app` back to `flutter_project`?

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73188432/flutter-firebase-is-it-safe-for-using-firebase-in-flutter) was closed but I think the answer does not relate to my question. So, I create a new question.

Comment: It's not that simple. Ever heard of decompilers? Yes, you can decompile an apk & might get some classes & methods signatures, some resource files, and even some keys. But restoring complete source code as it is?? You can't do that.

Comment: http://www.javadecompilers.com/ , see your self

Comment: Thank you for this information. I am new to this, So I think it is easy. But now I know this is very hard and not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I post this question on Facebook and did some research, I got the answer.

The flutter reverse engineering is impossible at the moment.
Because the flutter doesn't popular at the moment.
So, they don't create tools for flutter reverse engineering.
Although the flutter is popular. It's still hard.
Reverse engineering is hard and you can't get complete source code.

For those who worry about flutter reverse engineering, you can move the business logic to the server.

For me, I will use firebase in the flutter.
Because

- Save money(rent a host, domain name)
- Faster(flutter -> firebase -> flutter || flutter -> server -> firebase -> server -> flutter)
- Easy(Using only flutter || flutter, make API sent and receive)

In my opinion.
When the flutter is popular, the flutter team will make it safe and better, and the google team that creates the firebase package will do something for this issue.

I am just over thinking person(It's sad).